# objective c: read a csv file

Tags: objective-c, database, csv

I have this type of file:

@firstTablel: 1#one#two#three#four;
              2#apple#tower#flower#robot;

this is an example of my csv file..."firstTable" is my table and 1 and 2 are two id of my two item.

How I can read this file in objective c? Can you help me?

Comment: That doesn't look much like a "Comma-separated values" file...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cocoa for Scientists has a great post on reading CSV files: http://macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data

In your case, you'd do something like:

```
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:pathToFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:outError];
if (!fileString) {
    NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
}
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:fileString];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n#; "]];

NSString *id = nil, *hashOne = nil, *hashTwo = nil, *hashThree = nil, *hashFour = nil;
while ([scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&id] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&hashOne] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&hashTwo] && [scanner scanUpToString:@"#" intoString:&hashThree] && [scanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&hashFour]) {
     // Process the values as needed.
     NSLog(@"id:%@, 1:%@, 2:%@, 3:%@:, 4:%@", id, hashOne, hashTwo, hashThree, hashFour);
}
```

On the sample you've provided, this will print:

```
2011-03-31 13:55:07.846 Stephen[39304:903] id:1, 1:one, 2:two, 3:three:, 4:four
2011-03-31 13:55:07.849 Stephen[39304:903] id:2, 1:apple, 2:tower, 3:flower:, 4:robot
```

Comment: You didn't handle the "@firstTablel: ". Other than that, this is the way to go.

Comment: Use +[NSBundle pathForResource:@"csvFile" ofType:@"csv"] to get the full pathname (as an NSString) for the csv file.

Comment: ok...now i want store my items in an array because when I push a button I must show in some textfield the data of my single Item. Example: I push button1 an I must show in five textfield : id, hashOne, hashTwo, hashThree, hashFour; I have button1, button2 and textfield in my interface builder but now I ask you how store my data in array...thanks

Comment: You'll probably want to define a custom class that has all of these fields. Then you can create an NSMutableArray before the while loop in the scanner code provided above. Instead of NSLog-ing the data read in from the csv, create a new instance of your custom object and add it to the mutable array. At the end of the loop, you'll have an array of all the objects constructed from the csv data. So, when the user taps button1, you can call objectAtIndex:0 on the array and display the appropriate values in the text fields.